# MySQL create new column with average value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to solve an exercise that asks me to create a new column with the average salary of employees in each department.
My DB contains employees and departments table. **employees** is a list of employees with, among other data, the **salary** of each person and their **department_id**. departments contains **department_id** , **department_name** etc. I've already used **ALTER TABLE** to add a column called **AVG_SALARY** into **departments**. Now, I'd like to fill it with AVG salary based on **salary** column from **employee** table. So far, I came up with a lot of solutions, but neither worked. Some of them were:

```
UPDATE departments D 
INNER JOIN employees E ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
SET AVG_SALARY = AVG(employees.SALARY);
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

RESULT: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

```
UPDATE departments D
SET D.AVG_SALARY = 
(SELECT AVG(e.SALARY)
FROM employees E INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM departments) AS D ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY D.DEPARTMENT_ID);
```

> RESULT: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
INSERT INTO departments (DEPARTMENT_ID, AVG_SALARY)
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_ID, AVG(salary)
FROM EMPLOYEES E INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

> RESULT:Error Code: 1364. Field 'DEPARTMENT_NAME' doesn't have a
>   default value

Anyone able to help here?

Comment: For a better compression of the problem you can add details of the tables, columns , foreing key and others details important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one that is a modification of the one you made in second place:

```
UPDATE departments D
SET D.AVG_SALARY = 
    (SELECT AVG(e.SALARY)
     FROM employees E 
     where  D.DEPARTMENT_ID=E.DEPARTMENT_ID
     GROUP BY E.DEPARTMENT_ID);
```

Comment: The `group by` in the subquery is entirely unnecessary.  No real danger in this case, but it looks funny.